# RCurl and getURL problems with "

Tags: r

I download some JSON files from Twitter with this command

```
library(RCurl)
getURL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?since=2012-12-06&until=2012-12-07&q=royalbaby&result_type=recent&rpp=10&page=1")
```

But now all double quotes are transformed to \". In some special cases this destroys the JSON format. I think `getURL` or curl will make this change. Is there any way to suppress this action?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I think it's the print method: `print(x, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: works, but creates a lot of output. Is there any way to suppress the printing to the display?

Comment: You are confused between the string and the representation of the string. If a string contains \ in R, it will be represented as "\\".

Answer (score 1):

Your page contain the "\ , it is not Rcurl behavior ( try to open the page with a browser)

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
raw_data <- getURL(you.url)
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
```

The data is well formated.

Use cat to avoid \ representation.

Comment: for this example it works. But there are many which fail! E.g. try the #fcbayern

Comment: @MarkusSchmidberger can you give the exact link please?

Comment: out <- getURL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=12&max_id=276838217129529344&q=fcbayern%20since%3A2012-12-06%20until%3A2012-12-07&rpp=100&result_type=recent\",\"previous_page\":\"?page=11&max_id=276838217129529344&q=fcbayern%20since%3A2012-12-06%20until%3A2012-12-07&rpp=100&result_type=recent") fromJSON(out)
Fehler in fromJSON(out) : unexpected escaped character '\o'

Comment: or this one: getURL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=12&max_id=276838217129529344&q=fcbayern%20since%3A2012-12-06%20until%3A2012-12-07&rpp=94&result_type=recent")

Comment: Works for me. I am running linux. If you are running windows maybe its an encoding issue.